# Parsing 2 files

Tags: sed, xml

I'm trying to parse 2 `Microsoft Office` files called `v64.hash` and `VersionDescriptor.xml`.
Keep in mind that the contents of the files will change with every `Microsoft Office` update.

I would like to:

1. Print just a second line from `v64.hash`:

   ```
   4172FC3F5555BA53FDF7F830773F0696
   16.0.9226.2126
   ```
2. Print every `attribute="value"` for tags in `<Version>` tag in `VersionDescriptor.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Version>
      <Available Build="16.0.9226.2126" I320Hash="0A735F1D1A6E7691006B0AC7A05F458A" I640Hash="2A462E7150280626AA23F8D362D048C3" I320Version="16.0.9226.2126" I640Version="16.0.9226.2126" />
      <DeliveryMechanism FFNRoot="492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60" />
      <CreatedTimeUtc Value="05/11/2018 17:29" />
   </Version>
   ```

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? It's answered correctly

Comment: I dunno. Because the question does not contain any example except for a link? Linking to external sites is not really ideal, as the linked document may disappear without notice. That would render the question useless to anyone reading it.

Comment: The linked document is static

Comment: @Sukkan -1 | For please avoid such links if unnecessary. And I don't see a reason for a link in this case. Include the contents of the linked files instead.

Comment: As you said, the contents will change. Probably the xml structure will vary in a way that will break current regexp parsing, so you may think about using an xml tool for extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, extracting the second line of `v64.hash`:

```
$ sed -n '2p' v64.hash
16.0.9226.2126
```

Alternatively, getting the *last* line of the file:

```
$ tail -n 1 v64.hash
16.0.9226.2126
```

---

For the second question, extracting all `attribute=value` pairs from that piece of XML:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '/Version/*/@*' -v 'concat(name(), "=", .)' -nl VersionDescriptor.xml
Build=16.0.9226.2126
I320Hash=0A735F1D1A6E7691006B0AC7A05F458A
I640Hash=2A462E7150280626AA23F8D362D048C3
I320Version=16.0.9226.2126
I640Version=16.0.9226.2126
FFNRoot=492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60
Value=05/11/2018 17:29
```

This is using [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to first match all attributes of all child nodes of the `Version` node in the XML document, and then to create the concatenation of the attributes' names and values (with a `=` in-between).

Answer (score 0):

For the first file, best way is to do the `tail -n 1 v64.hash`.
This will get you just the last line of text in the `v64.hash`.

Parsing of the second file, I would do with:

```
sed -En '/^\s*<Version>\s*$/,/^\s*<\/Version>\s*$/ {
    /^\s*<Version>\s*$/ d
    /^\s*<\/Version>\s*$/ d

    s|^\s*<[^ ]+\s*(.*")\s*/>\s*|\1|
    p
}' VersionDescriptor.xml
```

`-E` Use extended regex.

`-n` Do not print the output unless explicitly told to.

`/^\s*<Version>\s*$/,/^\s*<\/Version>\s*$/` Work only for the lines between `[spaces]<Version>[spaces]` and `[spaces]</Version>[spaces]`, including those lines.

`/^\s*<Version>\s*$/ d` If the line is `[spaces]<Version>[spaces]`, ignore it.

`/^\s*<\/Version>\s*$/ d` If the line is `[spaces]</Version>[spaces]`, ignore it.

`s|^\s*<[^ ]+\s*(.*")\s*/>\s*|\1|` Remove the `[spaces]<[spaces]` from beginning of the line and `[spaces]/>[spaces]` from the end of the line.

`p` Print the current line after substitution.